# Function Declaration of useIsFirstRender()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, boolean, react-custom-hooks

I am working on a React coding challenge ([problem link](https://bigfrontend.dev/react/useIsFirstRender)) and the solution is [here](https://bigfrontend.dev/react/useIsFirstRender/aisolution).

In the problem, the custom hook returns true for the first render, otherwise returns false.

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export function useIsFirstRender(): boolean {
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  if (isFirstRender.current) {
    isFirstRender.current = false;
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

In the codes above, I don't get the way to declare this function. What exactly useIsFirstRender(): boolean {} means?

And since isFirstRender.current is defined as true in the function, It sounds like it will return true at any renders.

Do I misunderstand the usage of useRef? Thank you!

Comment: the `: boolean` is the return type, the data type of the value that this function returns. This is TypeScript syntax and is not part of JavaScript itself.

Comment: As for `useRef(true)`, the `true` is the initial value. `useRef` allows you to use persistent values between renders. So your if-statement should work and be `true` on the first time `useIsFirstRender()` is called and be `false` every time after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't get the way to declare this function. What exactly `useIsFirstRender(): boolean {}` means?

That's [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) code, not JavaScript code. The `: boolean` part means it returns a `boolean` value.

> And since `isFirstRender.current` is defined as `true` in the function, It sounds like it will return `true` at any renders.

`isFirstRender.current` isn't always `true`. [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) gives you a mutable ref object, and it always gives you the **same** mutable ref object on every call (for that `useRef` in that hook/component). (The ref object is stored in the instance information of the component this hook is being called by.) In the *first* call, it initializes the ref object's `current` property with the value you provide to `useRef`, but it only does that during the first call, not subsequent calls. If you can change the `current` value (as you see that code does), that change endures from call to call. That's one of the points of refs: They let you store instance-specific, durable information connected to the lifecycle of the element the function component (or the hooks it calls) are managing.

Here's an example with some logging that may help clarify it (using just JavaScript, not TypeScript):

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

function useIsFirstRender(): boolean {
    console.log(`useIsFirstRender called`);
    const isFirstRender = useRef(true);
    console.log(`isFirstRender.current = ${isFirstRender.current}`);

    if (isFirstRender.current) {
        console.log(`First render; setting isFirstRender.current to false`);
        isFirstRender.current = false;
        return true;
    }

    console.log(`Not first render`);
    return false;
}
const Example = () => {
    console.log(`Example called`);
    const isFirst = useIsFirstRender();
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>isFirst: {isFirst}</div>
            <div>
                Counter: {counter}{" "}
                <input type="button" value="+" onClick={() => setCounter((c) => c + 1)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Notice how the `isFirstRender.current` value is only `true` the first time `useIsFirstRender` is called for the mounted element, not for subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1):

the `: boolean` is the return type, the data type of the value that this function returns. This is TypeScript syntax and is not part of JavaScript itself.

As for `useRef(true)`, the `true` is the initial value. `useRef` allows you to use persistent values between renders. So your if-statement should work and be `true` on the first time `useIsFirstRender()` is called and be `false` every time after that.